# Countdown Timer Warning

Tags: vb.net, timer

How to make one Minute or make labeltime.text forecolor red

```
 Private Sub tmrCountdown_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrCountdown.Tick
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = TargetDT.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
    If ts.TotalMilliseconds > 0 Then
        lblTime.Text = ts.ToString("mm\:ss")
    Else
        lblTime.Text = "00:00"
        tmrCountdown.Stop()
        MessageBox.Show("Times Up")

        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please edit and try to clarify what you mean.

Comment: I mean how to make a warning if the timer have only one Minute

Comment: Check if `Math.Floor(ts.TotalSeconds)` is 60??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some rearrangement of your code should do the trick,

```
    If ts.TotalMilliseconds <= 0 Then
        'times up
        lblTime.Text = "00:00"
        tmrCountdown.Stop()
        MessageBox.Show("Times Up")
        Me.Close()
    ElseIf ts.TotalMilliseconds <= 60 * 1000 Then
        'one minute or less
        lblTime.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblTime.Text = ts.ToString("mm\:ss")
    Else
        'more than a minute
        lblTime.ForeColor = Color.Black
        lblTime.Text = ts.ToString("mm\:ss")
    End If
```

Comment: Let me try this one sir